# Double-type seconds between Joda-Time DateTimes

Tags: jodatime

I can get the integral number of seconds between two DateTimes using the [`Seconds`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html) class:

`Seconds.secondsBetween(now, dateTime);`

However, it's not clear to me how the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) would have me get the difference with fractional seconds, i.e. seconds as a double? Do I need to calculate fractional seconds from milliseconds or ticks? The API is generally so elegant and expressive, I feel like I might be missing something...

Comment: I had some similar issue with JodaTime. Short answer: No, there is no 'easy' way to get fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too hard… Use the [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Example code in Java 7…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// A good practice is to specify your time zone rather than rely on default.
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone californiaTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");

// Now.
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime(californiaTimeZone);

// Wait a moment.
try {
    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Later.
org.joda.time.DateTime aMomentLater = new org.joda.time.DateTime(californiaTimeZone);

// Elapsed.
org.joda.time.Interval interval = new org.joda.time.Interval( now, aMomentLater );
long milliseconds = interval.toDurationMillis();
double seconds = ( (double)milliseconds / 1000 );

// Display
System.out.println( "Elapsed: " + seconds + " seconds.  ( " + milliseconds + " milliseconds )");
```

When run…

```
Elapsed: 3.533 seconds.  ( 3533 milliseconds )
```

As a convenience method…

```java
double elapsedSeconds( org.joda.time.DateTime start, org.joda.time.DateTime stop )
{
    org.joda.time.Interval interval = new org.joda.time.Interval( start, stop );
    long milliseconds = interval.toDurationMillis();
    double seconds = ( (double)milliseconds / 1000 );
    return seconds;
}
```

Example usage…

```java
System.out.println( "Calculating Elapsed: " + myObject.elapsedSeconds(now, aMomentLater) );
```

Comment: Thanks, Basil.  This is similar to the approach I've taken thus far-- calculate the difference in milliseconds and then convert to seconds.  Perhaps conversion from millis or ticks is the only option?

Comment: @HolySamosa Yes, if you want fractional seconds, use milliseconds and multiply by a thousand. If you want whole seconds, use the [Seconds](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html) class in Joda-Time 2.3. Example using the `interval` variable created in the source code of this answer: `org.joda.time.Seconds.secondsIn( interval ).toSeconds()`